# Why is RWST ... m a not an instance of MonadReader, MonadState, MonadWriter

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I just discovered that `RWST` (from `transformers`)  does not carry an instance for `MonadReader`, `MonadState`, or `MonadWriter`. This seems a little odd to me as those instances would immediately improve usability, e.g. being able to use `.=`, or just generally improve reusability.

Surely there is a reason for this decision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RWST` is an instance of all those classes. You won't see that in the Haddock documentation for `transformers` because the classes and the instances you seek are in `mtl`.